# Configuring SharePoint Online Guest Access for GDPDR (Data privacy)

Tags: sharepoint-online, external-sharing

Is there a way to turn off the share panel only for guest / external users? this is a serious GDPDR related problem (data privacy). I need them to be able to access the site but not to access the share panel. In fact, I need them to not be able to even access that panel because searching for users is also a problem.

I already know the setting in sharepoint admin center (see screen), but this doesnt help for searching for users in share panel.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct setting to turn off the share panel only for guest/external users, and there is no way to block them search user in share panel.

As a workaround, you could set the sharing permissions for site collection only site owners can share files, folders and the site or people with edit permission to share as shown below:

[image]

Comment: thanks, but that is already configured and doesnt help. the share button is still available for guest users (which have just read permission!) and they could therefore open the dialog in which they could see all other users.

Comment: It's the default behavior that read permission user will see the share button,I am afraid you need to use code solution to hide it.Reference:https://www.codeproject.com/articles/678653/how-to-check-user-permission-for-the-web-list-or-s